# How to hinge an object and apply physics?

Tags: physics

I'm trying to hinge a modified torus to a hole made to a modified cube.

Torus: physics: rigid body | dynamic ON | Collisions shape: Mesh

Cube: physics: rigid body | dynamic OFF | Collisions shape: Mesh

But during simulation the torus simply flies off, instead of hanging.
[Model screenshot attached]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0API.png)

Blender version: 2.73a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your described set up works fine.

[image]

> The Rigid Body World
>
> [image]
>
> The dynamic chain element
>   [image]
>
> The static collision object
>   [image]

Start trouble-shooting

- Double check your settings.
- Create a duplicate of your file and delete everything except the problem area.
- Create the scene from scratch and append it to your file.
- ...

Comment: I started from scratch again for the problem area. Now it works. Thanks.

Comment: Earlier, I made the objects small (few cm). May be that's why it failed.

Comment: I changed the sensitivity margin under Rigid Body Collisions to an appropriate small value. Now it is working.

Comment: Your*          ‫‫ ​‍‎‏‫‬‭

Comment: Also, sometimes hitting CTRL A helps too.